# Combine datasets of different domains to ehance generalizibility

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, dataset

so I try to implement an Emotion Classifier, which should detect several emotions from a text. There are several datasets for this (ISear, GoEmotions, etc.). However, a lot of them come from different domains, e.g. from Chats, Blogs, Newsarticles, etc.

My Emotion Classifier should not be limited to a domain, so I basically combined each dataset (where I only considered the emotion: anger, disgust, neutral, happy, fear) and trained my model with it. My goal is to get an Emotion Classifier which generalizes well, also maybe on unknown use cases. So everyone can use it. It is worth highlighting, that I got an accuracy from 63-67% for each dataset I used here.

Now I wanted to know is this a reasonable approach? Which challenges and disadvantages are possible? Is there a paper, which is specifically discussing this kind of topic? Or do you have another idea how I could possibly solve this differently

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sounds reasonable indeed, but I would suggest to verify this experimentally:

Since you have access to multiple heterogeneous datasets, I think a good way to evaluate the ability of the model to generalize would be to train on all the datasets but one, and  then evaluate on the remaining dataset. Then preferably repeat with every dataset as test set in order to account for chance (similarly to cross-validation). To test whether the hypothesis works, you should also train baseline models using only one dataset and compare their performance on the same test sets.

Comment: I did not thought of that. I will also use that for my evaluation. Thank you!